# cv2.VideoCapture can not read remote video file

Tags: python, opencv

I have a video file and need to load it with OpenCV.

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:8080/xxx/2019-11-29.3gp')
print(vc.isOpened()) # get False
```

However, I get the following error

```
[tcp @ 000001a19a548b00] Connection to tcp://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:8080 failed: Error number -138 occurred
warning: Error opening file (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:901)
warning: http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:8080/xxx/2019-11-29.3gp 
(/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:902)
```

How can I solve?

Comment: Can you read files  stored in your local device ?

Comment: @Ziri I can read local files but not remote video